# javascript convert dotnotation string into objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string like this `"namespace.fun1.fun2.fun3"` passed from the client. It's telling the server which function to use.

How do I safely run the function?

right now i'm doing:

```
var runthis = string.split('.')
namespace[runthis[1]][runthis[2]][runthis[3]]
```

How do I handle arbitrary depth of nesting safely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little function I wrote. I use it in most of my applications:

```
Object.lookup = (function _lookup() {
    var cache = { };

    return function _lookupClosure( lookup, failGracefully ) {
        var check   = null,
            chain   = [ ],
            lastkey = '';

        if( typeof lookup === 'string' ) {
            if( cache[ lookup ] ) {
                chain = cache[ lookup ].chain;
                check = cache[ lookup ].check;
            }
            else {
                lookup.split( /\./ ).forEach(function _forEach( key, index, arr ) {
                    if( check ) {
                        if( typeof check === 'object' ) {
                            if( key in check ) {
                                chain.push( check = check[ key ] );
                                lastkey = key;
                            }
                            else {
                                if( !failGracefully ) {
                                    throw new TypeError( 'cannot resolve "' + key + '" in ' + lastkey );    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if( !failGracefully ) {
                                throw new TypeError( '"' + check + '" ' + ' does not seem to be an object' );   
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        lastkey = key;
                        chain.push( check = window[ key ] );
                    }
                });

                if( check ) {
                    cache[ lookup ] = {
                        chain: chain,
                        check: check
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        return {
            execute: function _execute() {
                return typeof check === 'function' ? check.apply( chain[chain.length - 2], arguments ) : null;
            },
            get: function _get() {
                return check;
            }
        };
    }
}());
```

---

**usage:**

```
Object.lookup( 'namespace.fun1.fun2.fun3' ).execute();
```

The first parameter is the object/method/property to resolve. The second (optional) parameter indicates whether or not the `lookup()` method shall fail silently or throw an exception if some property or object could not get resolved. default is 'throw'. To avoid that call

```
Object.lookup( 'namespace.fun1.fun2.fun3', true ).execute( 'with', 'paras' );
```

If `.fun3` is a function, you can pass in any parameters into `.execute()` instead.
if you just want to receive the property value, you can also call `.get()` instead of `.execute()`

```
var val = Object.lookup( 'namespace.fun1.fun2.fun3' ).get();
```

Comment: That's likely far more complex that this needs here.

Comment: @Squeegy: I don't see the 'complex' part.Probably the local caching ? which is a pretty good idea if you're using such a function quite a lot.

Comment: @Harry: well I've updated the method. Should work better now.

Comment: @Harry: Oh true, you need just to replace it by `global`

Comment: Why check === 'object'? Should be fine if it's also a function right.

Answer (score 2):

(I may be misinterpreting the question, but this is what came to mind)

```
var s = "space.f.g.h.i.j.k.l.m",
  a = s.split( "." ),
  fn = eval( a[0] );

for ( var i = 1; i < a.length; i++ ) {
  fn = fn[ a[i] ];
}

fn();
```

Note: this won't guard against the namespace being specified incorrectly or maliciously.

Comment: That's unsafe. You're allowing a client to run you into a TypeError without even making it hard...

Comment: furthermore, I would avoid `eval()` at all costs in a server-environment. Especially if the data comes from somewhere else (like in this case). Asking for terrible trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
var get = function(obj, key) {
  var s = key.split('.')
    , i = 1
    , l = s.length;

  for (; i < l; i++) {
    obj = obj[s[i]];
    if (!obj) return;
  }

  return obj;
};

get({hello:{world:{}}}, 'ns.hello.world');
```

edit: changed code a bit

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple for loop that should do find each object specified strating from the global scope, and then run the function it finds.

```
window.namespace = { fun1: { fun2: { fun3: function() { alert('hi!') }}}};

runFunc = function(address) {
    var addressArray = address.split('.'),
        current = window,
        i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
        current = current[addressArray[i]];
    }

    current();
};

runFunc('namespace.fun1.fun2.fun3');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jfWra/1/

And here's some eror protection that will throw something meaningful if the value referenced doesnt exist or is not a function: http://jsfiddle.net/jfWra/2/

Comment: this will fail if any level is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another simple solution using a recursive function:

```
function run(str, context) {
  var path = str.split(".")
  if path.length == 1 {
     context[path[0]].call()
     return;
  }

  if(typeof context == 'undefined') {
     context = window[path[0]]
  } else {
     context = context[path[0]]
  }
  run(path.splice(1).join('.'), context)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two years later there is this module: https://github.com/daaku/nodejs-dotaccess.

```
var get = require("dotaccess").get;
var o = {a:{b:{c:'deep'}}};
console.log(get(o, 'a.b.c'));
```