# Better way to test for existence of a nested property in an object

Tags: javascript

I'm working with javascript objects that have nested properties I need to test for, like

```
myObject = {
    'some' : {
        'nested' : {
            'property' : {
                'foo' : 'bar'
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The trouble is `myObject.some` might not exist, nor `myObject.some.nested`, and so on. So to test for the existence of `myObject.some.nested.property.foo` I have to do this:

```
if (myObject.some) {
    if (myObject.some.nested) {
        if (myObject.some.nested.property) {
            if (myObject.some.nested.property.foo) {
                // do something with myObject.some.nested.property.foo here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

because if I do `if (myObject.some.nested.property.foo)` and one of the parent properties doesn't exist, it throws the error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'myObject.some.nested.property.foo')
```

Is there a better way to test for nested properties without using so many `if` statements?

Comment: There are plenty of other dupes such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343028/in-javascript-test-for-property-deeply-nested-in-object-graph or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927242/whats-the-simplest-approach-to-check-existence-of-deeply-nested-object-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate safely to it. `foo` will evaluate to `false` in case you don't get all the way.

```
var foo = myObject.some && myObject.some.nested && myObject.some.nested.property;
if(foo)
    //use foo
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7LFp/